# Select option doesn't style in QQ email for Android app

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

When I open the link from QQ email for Android app, all options' `background-color` and `font-color` are white.

Alert the `userAgent`:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; MI 3 Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36